# BMI calculator not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    double w, h, b;
    printf("Enter your weight in pounds \n");
    scanf("%d", &w);
    printf("Enter your height in inches \n");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    h = h/12;
    b = w*703 / (h*h);
    if (b < 18.5) {
        printf("underweight");
    } else if (b>=18.5 && b<25) {
        printf("normal");
    } else {
        printf("overweight");
    }
    system("Pause");
}
```

ok so my code prints "Underweight* no matter what numbers I type in and I have no idea why.  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You're reading in the numbers as integers when they're doubles. You want

`scanf("%lf", &w);`

etc.

Comment: Thank you! It works now :)  As you can probably tell Im just learning C

Comment: @user1984103 Read your C book and/or a C reference. `scanf()` and `%lf` are described there!